# Polymer2: how to share data from parent to deeply nested component?

Tags: polymer, singleton, web-component, flux, polymer-2.x

I am wondering what would be the best idea in case of passing data from parent component to deeply nested component while is use Polymer2.

For example,

```
    <a some-prop="1">
      <b>
        <c>
          <d>
            <e></e>
          </d>
        </c>
      </b>
    </a>
```

I'd like to pass `some-prop` from `a` to `e`.

To solve this issue, I have a couple of ideas:

- Singleton service: Such as AngularJs or Angular2.x. But Polymer doesn't provide singleton service by default.
- Flux pattern: Like Redux, Vuex. But my app is not complex enough to use this pattern. Plus has to implement this pattern by using Polymer.
- `e` does NOT use `some-prop` and just fire an event from `e` and `a` will handle whatever I want: By doing this, there won't be need passing `some-prop`.

What would be the best way to handle this situation?

How Polymer is designed to share data between components?

Thanks.

Comment: One way data-binding is the way to go.
Binding data to the child elements down to your component "e" and sending events up when data is changed

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the data between elements or child elements very easy: Here an example:

[Demo](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/RwNpXEN?editors=1001):

```
  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
         <a-a some-prop="{{someProp}}">
          <b-b>
            <c-c>
              <d-d>
                <e-e some-prop={{someProp}}>
                </e-e>
              </d-d>
            </c-c>
          </b-b>
        </a-a>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
```

- Remember: custom elements should be named with min two char with dash-separated.